# Placing Google Map in a fragment, without using FragmentActivity in Android App

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments

So I am trying to get a Google Map into a fragment which will be used in a ViewPager with tabs. I am having trouble initiating the map, specifically on this line:

`map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();`

If I don't try to fetch the map this way, the map does display, so I know everything is right in the dev console. When I try to run this program I get a NullPointerException. Any ideas on why?

**Fragment:**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;

public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

private GoogleMap map;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_movies,
            container, false);

    // create map
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    return rootView;

}
}
```

**Layout**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:name="com.example.test.HomeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Logcat:**

```
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at com.example.test.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:24)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:478)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1068)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:914)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1436)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at     android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:302)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5012)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2451)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.View.measure(View.java:15855)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1905)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1104)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1284)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1004)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5481)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:749)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:562)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:532)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:735)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:739)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:555)
08-22 16:19:09.946: E/AndroidRuntime(19710):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: FWIW, here is a sample project demonstrating loading maps into a `ViewPager`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Pager

Answer (score 1):

**problem:**

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
```

You are trying to cast the map fragment as a `SupportMapFragment` but in your xml you specify it as a `MapFragment`.

solution change it to `SupportMapFragment`

**sample:**

```
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
```